# Python if Statement doesn't meet condition but it appears to meet the condition

Tags: python, pyautogui, pyperclip

I don't understand why my if statement doesn't work.

```
a = "one"

if a == "one":

    print(a)

elif a == "two":

    print(a)

elif a == "three":

    print(a)
```

The above works correctly but, when I use this code to copy an excel cell that equals one none of the conditions are triggered.

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

a = pyperclip.paste()

if a == "one":

    print(a)

elif a == "two":

    print(a)

elif a == "three":

    print(a)
```

Also if I run print(a) it will print out "one" which is exactly what the if statement is looking for.

Why does the if statement not trigger?

Comment: try str(a), just to make sure you are comparing the same classes.

Comment: Also try `a.strip()` to remove any whitespace and newlines.

Comment: Please double-check what you paste here; I assume your actual code must have the missing colons, and no `elsif`, or else you'd getting a syntax error instead.

Comment: @CrazyChucky you are right, thank you for pointing it out.